# Android Edit Text Covered By Keyboard on Second Tap

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard

So I have an EditText that does not get covered by the keyboard the first time around. Then when you close the keyboard and tap the edittext again it covers the edittext.

I have spent hours researching this issue and have come to the conclusion it has something to do with these two properties of the edit text.

```
android:inputType="number"
android:gravity="center"
```

If I remove either one of those the adjustPan (as put in my manifest) works all the time as promised. Seems to be an Android bug. But I need both of these lines in my edit text. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Here is a slightly condensed version of xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/generate_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/buttonColor"
        android:elevation="@dimen/button_elevation"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="@string/generate"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/generate_button_title_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/copy_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/buttonColor"
        android:elevation="@dimen/button_elevation"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_copy"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttons_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    </GridLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="11"
        android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColorHint">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num_rolls_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/number_of_rolls"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="@integer/edit_text_max_length"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_text_size"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what it should look like every time...
[image]

Here is what it looks like on the second tap currently (keyboard covers edittext)...
[image]

**EDIT:** I have discovered the keyboard works fine when using Android 7.0. I don't think it works on anything below that. Was this a bug that was recently fixed or something?

Also, I have included android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" in both my application and activity part of my manifest but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Can you post xml?

Comment: @gunessun XML posted

Answer (score 5):

Add this in your manifest for activity. It works fine

```
 <activity android:name=".Views.UI.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
```

Answer (score 4):

Try changing `adjustPan` to `adjustResize` for the activity config in manifest file, as the [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) suggested it.

> This (adjustPan) is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

**EDIT**

If you don't want the views to be crushed/adjusted when keyboard is opened, add a `ScrollView` to your root `RelativeLayout`. So that when `adjustResize` will scroll the view accordingly instead of "crushing" them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried that before and it just crushes the views, especially the edit text, so you can barely see it. I'm sticking with adjustPan

Comment: But adding a scroll view screwsup the inside linear layouts that need a relativelayout. Scrollview disables the android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` in the `ScrollView` tag, and make sure your `ScrollView` has `match_parent` as height. @Jared

Answer (score 2):

I think you did not use scroll view inside XML if you did it than you need to make some code android mainfeast. `<activity
            android:name=".activity.ActivityProductDetail"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" />`

Comment: I've already tried scrollviews, adjustResize, and they both don't work corectly.

Answer (score 2):

In your first Screenshot the text "Dice" is cutoff, in the second, where the editText is covered, "Dice" is shown, consider removing the Title editText "Dice"?

Also i see you've used scrollView and said you can use `AlignParentBottom`, could you replace that with `layoutBelow`?

Comment: Or is it possible "Dice" is your Title Bar?

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` with `alignParentBottom` and several views is always problematic, especially with keyboard. I would suggest using `scrollview` and adding views inside `LinearLayout`, where the buttons will be at the end, but not surely at the bottom of the view.

Then you don't even need to use `adjustPan`. Something like:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- grid view + textview + textEdit + your buttons at the end -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add your layout into `ScrollView` and listen `onGloablLayout()` callback. If rootview and your view's height diffrence is  >100 pixels it's probably keyboard and you could scroll to your `EditText` so It's not blocked by keyboard.

```
final View layout = findViewById(R.id.layoutparentID);
    layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int heightDiff = layout.getRootView().getHeight() - layout.getHeight();
            if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...

                final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, editText.getBottom());
                    }
                };
                activityRootView.getHandler().postDelayed(r, 100);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, hiding soft keyboard

```
 try {
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```